# dijit.Dialog.hide() exception in animation handler for: onEnd

Tags: dojo

I am creating a dijit Dialog and then hiding it with a OK/Cancel button. As the dialog hides, I *always* get the follow errors in the javascript console:

```
exception in animation handler for: onEnd
TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined(…)
```

See here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QcEUsllrRGs

The error doesn't seem to affect anything, but I'd sure love to resolve it so I don't confuse that error for a real functional issue while debugging.

I've read many suggestions regarding similar errors... using lang.hitch, disconnecting from events, but nothing seems to work/be applicable. Help?!

Here's a snippet of my Dialog code:

```
function showMessageDialog(title, message, width) {
    var content,
        focusOnOkButton = function () {
            dojo.byId('messageDialogOk').focus();
        };
    if (!dijit.byId("messageDialog")) {
        new dijit.Dialog({}, "messageDialog").startup();

        new dijit.form.Button({
            onClick: function() {
                dijit.byId('messageDialog').hide();
            }
        }, "messageDialogOk").startup();
    }

    if (width) {
        dojo.byId('messageDialogTable').style.width = width + "px";
    } else {
        dojo.byId('messageDialogTable').style.width = "450px";
    }
    dijit.byId('messageDialog').resize();
    dijit.byId('messageDialog').set("title", title);
    content = dojo.byId("messageDialogMessage");
    dojo.empty(content);
    content.innerHTML = message;
    dijit.byId('messageDialog').show();
    setTimeout(focusOnOkButton, 50);
}
```

....and the associated HTML:

```
<div id="messageDialog" style="display:none;">
    <table id="messageDialogTable" style="width:450px;table-layout: fixed;">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="padding: 0 0px 0px 5px;">
                <table style="width: 100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td id="messageDialogMessage" style="font-size: 10pt;"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 5px;text-align: center;">
                            <div id="messageDialogOk">OK</div>
                        </td>                                   
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I tried to duplicate the problem with a simple JSFiddle example, but could not... so there's something going in in my app... but not sure what it could be.